# Using R for loop to create a time series

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm forecasting a stock price 'St1' starting at 'Stt = 10' at time t. Dates are not important. I want to find the next 100 prices using the following formula:

```
St1 <- Stt*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T/n+sigma*E*sqrt(T/n))
```

So I'm starting with 10 and then need the next 100 values and put it in a data.frame or whatever is easy. How do I do this? I'm stuck trying this...

```
Stt = 10
r = 0.15
sigma = 0.2
T = 1
n = 100
E = 0.15

St1 = Stt
for (i in 1:100)
{
    St1[i] <- Stt*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T/n+sigma*E*sqrt(T/n))
}
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is this

```
r = 0.15
sigma = 0.2
T = 1
n = 100
E = 0.15

Stt<- rep(NA,n) # preallocate
Stt[1] <- 10
for (i in 2:100)
{
    Stt[i] <- Stt[i-1]*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T/n+sigma*E*sqrt(T/n))
}
```

Without `for` loop, and in order to use `rnorm` for `E`, this code could work:

```
# for fixed E of length one
Stt <- cumprod(c(10,rep(exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T/n+sigma*E*sqrt(T/n)), n-1)))

# for random vector E 
E <- rnorm(n-1, mean=0.15, sd=0.01)
Stt <- cumprod(c(10, exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T/n+sigma*E*sqrt(T/n))))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, tnx a lot!

Comment: What if I wanted to make E a normal random variabel?
 rnorm(100) - gives me error message "  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: In the formula, replace E by E[i] since E is a vector. By the way, I would recommend you to vectorize the whole formula.